# Run a SQL query on a DB2 file with a dot "." in the name?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a DB2 file with a name like "my.test". The DB2 filename contains a dot `'.'`

If I try and run the following query via strsql:

```
select * from my.test
```

I receive the following error:

```
Token . was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.
```

Is there a way around this? I tried surrounding it in quotes but that doesn't help.

Comment: What system is this on; is it possible this is a system/SQL naming issue?  What happens if you replace the `'.'` with `'/'`?

Comment: It's an IBM i. If I runt his query "select * from my/test" I get an error "TEST in MY type *FILE not found"

Comment: ...It just hit me that you probably meant that you have a `'.'` in the actual name of the file, right?  Try surrounding the file name with single quotes (apostrophes - `'`)?  If that is what you've done, I _don't_ recommend putting periods in table/library/etc names, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @X-Zero yup that's right. The filename contains a '.' in it. I'll try apostrophes. I don't recommend it either! Unfortunately I've inherited  these. I think they are legacy file.s

Comment: Tried `select * from "my.file"` and got a `"my.file" in *LIBL type *FILE not found.` even though the library is in my libl. Tried it with single quotes as well `select * from 'my.file'` but got a `Token 'my.file' was not valid. Valid tokens: ( NEW FINALTABLE UNNEST LATERAL XMLTABLE <IDENTIFIER>.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes are the correct way to escape the file name.  **The file name becomes case sensitive within quotes and must be specified in upper case**.

```
SELECT * FROM "MY.TEST"
```

---

Note that in the IFS naming convention the "." operator is used to reference members within a file but it doesn't work with SQL.

If you need to access a file named "MY" with a member named "TEST" you would need to create an alias to query against.

```
CREATE ALIAS QTEMP/MYTEST FOR MY (TEST)
SELECT * FROM QTEMP/MYTEST
```

Comment: Thanks JamesA but the it isn't a file named "MY" with a member named "TEST". It's actual file name is "MY.TEST". I believe these are legacy files from System 36. I'm going to see if I can make an alias of it though.

Comment: @sloopjohnB I included the member information just as additional information in case it applied.  You need to specify the file name in upper case within double quotes to fix your immediate issue.